# Using .sort with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

With PyMongo, when I try to retrieve objects sorted by their 'number' and 'date' fields like this:

```
db.test.find({"number": {"$gt": 1}}).sort({"number": 1, "date": -1})
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list
```

What's wrong with my sort query?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

`sort` should be a list of key-direction pairs, that is

```
db.test.find({"number": {"$gt": 1}}).sort([("number", 1), ("date", -1)])
```

The reason why this has to be a list is that the ordering of the arguments matters and `dict`s are not ordered in Python < 3.6

Comment: The reason that this is a list in Python is that the ordering of the arguments to `sort()` matters and dicts are not ordered in Python.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo can an OrderedDict() be used?

Comment: @yourfriendzak, I'm afraid not. It's a bit unpythonic, I guess. [Here's the reason why](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.0/pymongo-pysrc.html#L70), at line 70. An OrderedDict is not an instance of types.ListType.

Comment: This saved me a ton of research. The Little MongoDB Book misleads in sort examples.

Comment: If it is only one field, it can be .sort("_id", 1)

Comment: Kinda a bummer that mongodb's documentation examples use dictionaries instead of list of tuples, but it makes sense why pymongo needs them. JSONs are ordered dictionaries (as strings) -- pymong's error message could be clearer on what to change to solve the problem.

Comment: in python3.6+ dicts are ordered so if anyone is up for it, might be worth a pull request to pymongo to bring it in line with generic mongodb syntax. Of course this wouldn't work when running pymongo on older python versions..

Comment: if you want to sort a single field, this is another way

.sort('{}'.format('created_on'), 1 if sort_type == 'asc' else -1)