# Python Mongo Sorting based on field within a field

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, pymongo

I have entries in the shape of:

```
{
    outerField1 : {
                     "innerField" : 1
                 }
    outerField2 : "blah"
}
```

I'd like to sort them in descending order based on the innerField, but my understanding of the sort function is limited to knowing only how to sort based on the outer fields. How would I sort a mongo query based on an inner field?

Comment: Good question! Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I've tried stuff like sort({'o' : {'autoLaunched' : 1 }}) but so far no results. Still searching for possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subfields in documents can be accessed by using [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation) (e.g. `outerfield1.innerField`).

In Mongo shell you can do this sorting by using:

```
sort({'outerField1.innerField': -1})
```

If you are on Python, you may need to write instead:

```
sort([("outerField1.innerField": -1)])
```

The reason you need to do this is that Python's dict is an unordered data structure. For details, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10242305/117919

Comment: That gives me an error of:

    raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "
    TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list

Comment: descending order would be: `sort({'outerField1.innerField':-1})`  -1 indicates descending sort.

Comment: That has helped, now the issue is my dataset is too big to sort without an index apparently. I'll limit it by a $gt to see if that helps.

Comment: You can create an index out of `innerField` with the very same dot notation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#secondary-indexes

Comment: Also, if you don't have always `innerField` values present, consider using a sparse index: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-sparse