# find documents that mongodb moves with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to count in my mongodb profiler data all the documents, that have been moved when they were updated.

In the mongo shell I do this via:

`db.system.profile.find({op:"update", moved:true}).count()`

which works fine. But now I want to incorporate this into a python script where I am using pymongo.

My attempt looks like this:

`db.system.profile.find({'op':"update"},{'moved':"true"}).count()`

but I get the error message: `name 'moved' is not defined.`

I read the pymongo docu and did quite a bit of research and tried to understand how pymongo is treating the find command as in [Using .sort with PyMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242149/sorting-with-mongodb-and-python)
or here:
http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/01/moving-along-with-pymongo.html

but I don't find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I found a workaround for my problem. I am now looking for the nmoved tag instead like that: db.system.profile.find({'nmoved':{'$gt': 0}}).count(). Nevertheless I still would be interested in a solution for my initial question.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
db.system.profile.find({'op': 'update', 'moved': True}).count()
```

Just like in the shell.