# Text search using python in mongo db

Tags: python, mongodb, full-text-search, pymongo

I created indices on the text fields, the following query runs fine in Mongo.

```
cursor = db.collection.find({ "$text" : { "$search": "stack" } },{ "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } }).sort( {'score' : {'$meta': 'textScore'} }).skip(0).limit(4)
```

But when I run it using PyMongo, I get the following error:

> TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list

Comment: possible duplicate of [sorting with mongodb and python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242149/sorting-with-mongodb-and-python)

Comment: not quite a duplicate since text search has slightly different sort syntax.  OP: please include the actual code you used that gave the error.  It's also a good idea to include versions that you are using.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky this is the actual code, this line in particular gives error, I'm able to run other queries and I'm also able to run this query in mongo db terminal, but unable to run it using pymongo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the syntax in [pymongo docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort) for sort.

You don't show what actual syntax you are using in Python, but it should be like the example on that page:

```
cursor.sort([('score', {'$meta': 'textScore'})])
```