# Query by position in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I need to fetch the document in a mongodb collection using its position. I know the position of the document inside the collection exactly but could not figure out a way to pull those documents from collection. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
db.daily.find({'_id': {'$in': 0,5,8}})
```

This is what i tried but _id is not inserted as 1,2,3... but it has some random num Eg:57d8fd62f2a9d913ba0d006d. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by position, order ? If order then order by what _id ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. Please consider to add sample document with the expected result to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/#cursor.skip) and [limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) to query based on the position in the [natural order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-natural-order)

```
db.collection.find().skip(10).limit(1) // get 10th document in natural order
```

As the natural order link points out, the document order need not match the order that documents are inserted (with [an exception for capped collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11599283/5894196)).  If you use the default [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification) as the _id field for your documents you can sort by _id to order based on insertion in the collection (up to the resolution of the timestamp in the ObjectId)

```
db.collection.find().sort([("_id",1)]).skip(10).limit(1) // get 10th document in inserted order
```

You may also consider using your own _id or adding a field to be able to sort on in order to query based on the position you define.

Comment: Nice thanks, is there any way to get multiple documents in one query considering i have multiple positions ?

Comment: when i try this ` for i in range(0, 2):
        horolist.append(db.daily.find().sort({"_id": 1}).skip(i).limit(1)) ` i got an exception saying `TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list`

Comment: If they are contiguous you can use `limit(N)` to get N in a row.  Otherwise you should consider adding a position field and using `$in` or multi-range query on the field

Comment: I was giving mongo shell/js syntax.  For python you will need to use a list for `.sort([("_id", 1)])`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10242305/5894196  (updated answer to use python syntax)

Comment: Thank you.. It helped a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125521/uses-for-mongodb-objectid-creation-time .