# How to do a case-insensitive regex search of mongodb?

Tags: python, pymongo

I am trying to read data from mongodb database as below and running into couple of issues,can anyone provide guidance?

1. Running into below error, how to fix this?
2. Is there a way to do a case-insensitive search by regex, I have `"\%train\%"`as below, not sure if this is the right way

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os,pymongo
dbuser = os.environ.get('muser', 'techauto1')
dbpass = os.environ.get('mpwd', 'techpass')
uri = 'mongodb://{dbuser}:{dbpass}@machine.company.com:27017/techautomation'.format(**locals())
client = MongoClient(uri)
db = client.techautomation.tech_build_audit
try:
  #db.tech_build_audit
  myCursor = db.collection.find({"chip" : "4377","branch" : "\%train\%"}).sort({"_id":-1})
  print myCursor

except pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect, e:
  print e
```

Errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "parseplist.py", line 11, in
>
> myCursor = db.collection.find({"chip" : "4377","branch" : "%peaceB%"}).sort({"_id":-1})
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 703, in sort
>           keys = helpers._index_list(key_or_list, direction)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 52, in _index_list
>
> raise TypeError("if no direction is specified, "
>
> TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list

**UPDATE:**

I am not able to verify if the regex works because of the error,how do I fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pythons `re` library for regex and `re.IGNORECASE` for your second problem, like this:

```
import re

### rest of your code
regx = re.compile("^foo", re.IGNORECASE)
myCursor = db.collection.find({"chip" : "4377","branch" : regx}).sort({"_id":-1})
print myCursor
```

About your updated question:

Thats another issue and its about using `sort()` with pymongo, you can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242149/using-sort-with-pymongo)

In short you should use `.sort()` like this: `.sort([("_id", -1)])`

Comment: Error @`TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list` still exists

Comment: @user2125827 thats another issue and its about using sort() with pymongo, you can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242149/using-sort-with-pymongo)

in short you should use `.sort()` like this: `.sort([("_id", -1)])`

Comment: I added the comment to my answer

Comment: actually that didnt work,`sort("_id", 1)` worked but printing `myCursor` doesnt print any value,how do I print the values?

Comment: @user2125827 I guess your database query result is empty!

Comment: No ,it has data

Comment: just to loop over the cursor instance,thanks

Comment: @user2125827 your'e welcome